# Texmaker: Shortcuts for new auto-complete commands

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion, keyboard

so I've added new autocomplete options for commands like \frac{@}{@}@ so that there is a placeholder after the function, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to now get a short-cut like Ctrl+Shift+F to insert this new command.

I've tried tweaking the .ini file (using the portable version at work) and there doesn't seem to be a way to include this new function as a shortcut. Unless it has something to do with the /6/0/ (and other numbers) that follows every shortcut in the .ini file?

Any help would be awesome, thank you!

P.S. I'm not averse to modifying some of the source files if required - just don't know where to start.